# Python Tornado file upload gives KeyError

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

I'm trying to write a very simple python script based on tornado web server to upload a file. But I'm getting 'KeyError' though the key is in the html form is OK.

Here is the python code just to see the uploaded file name.

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Bismillahir Rahmanir Raheem")
        self.render('form.html')

class UploadHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.write("Alhamdulillah, here")
        if  self.request.files is not None:
            self.write("Inside the if")
            uploadFile = self.request.files['my_file'][0]
            self.write(uploadFile['filename'])

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
      (r"/", IndexHandler),
      (r"/upload", UploadHandler)
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

And the html form is as below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing file upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Testing file upload</h1>
        <form enctype="multipart/formdata" method="post" action="/upload">
            <input type="file" name="my_file"/>
            <input type="Submit" name="upload" value="Upload"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

But each time I select a file and press Upload button I get the

500: Internal Server Error

And at the PyCharm editor I get the following error:
    File "C:/Users/Mushfique/Desktop/file-upload/upload.py", line 14, in post
    uploadFile = self.request.files['my_file'][0]

> KeyError: 'my_file' ERROR:tornado.access:500 POST /upload (::1) 1.00ms

Though in the html form I've used 'my_file' as the file input field name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a typo there:

```
<form enctype="multipart/formdata" ...>
                         ^^^^ this is a typo
```

It should be [**`multipart/form-data`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) (note the hyphen).

Comment: Ops! Since I am new in python and also in Tornado I thought it must be something unknown problem to me. My bad. :(
Whatever thanks for your answer.